# IPv6 to LXC container

Tags: linux-networking, lxc

I've got an ipv6 /64 subnet and use lxc/lxd with many container. The ipv6 /64 subnet is attached to eth0. Now I want every container get an ipv6 (maybe in an /56 subnet of this /64?) and be available extern.

How do I get this setup?